# Render happens before componentwillmount Meteor API call

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm having some trouble with async. It seems that the render is called before the api call is done in the componentwillmount

```
// Framework
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";

// Components
import Page from "../components/Page.jsx";
import Button from "../components/Button.jsx";

class Home extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      order: null,
      error: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Meteor.call("orders.getLastOrder", (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        this.setState(() => ({ error: error }));
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        this.setState(() => ({ order: response }));
        console.log(this.state.order[0].name);
      }
    });
  }

  goBack = () => this.props.history.push("/shop");
  goCart = () => this.props.history.push("/cart");

  render() {
    return (
      <Page pageTitle="Cart" history goBack={this.goBack} goCart={this.goCart}>
        <div className="home-page">
          <div>
          {this.state.order.map((item, i) => <div key={i}> {item.name}  
                      {item.price} {item.quantity}</div>)}
            </div>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              this.props.history.push("/shop");
            }}
          >
            Go shopping
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Page>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to loop through the objects from my state and display them in rows (I'm trying to create a cart)

```
0:{name: "TEMPOR Top", price: 875.5, quantitiy: 6}
1:{name: "CONSECTETUR Coat", price: 329.8, quantitiy: 3}
_id:"6RNZustHwbKjQDCYa"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will still get the extra `render` but I assume you getting an error on the `.map()` function?

if you only change your constructor into this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        order: [],
        error: null
    };
}
```

you won't get the error, because you can't use .map on a null object but you can use it on a empty array.